# APK generation is changing size of .so file

Tags: android, md5, .so

In an apk, I'm using an aar library which includes a native library. Trying to calculate the MD5 checksum of the .so file in runtime, I noticed that it was different from the .so file inside of the aar. The size of the file also changes: the file in the apk weights about 20 bytes less. Does anybody know why the apk generation process is modifying this kind of files? Is there anything I can do to keep the file intact?

It only happens for the arm64 version.

Comment: is the native library included as a precompiled binary file, or is it compiled and built by the NDK?

Comment: Compiled and built by Gomobile and then copied in the final .aar library.

Answer (score 0):

In my app/build folder, I saw that the .so file was also located in intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs and intermediates/transforms/stripDebugSymbol. The md5sum of the .so file in mergeJniLibs matched the original .so file's sum. The md5sum of the .so file in stripDebugSymbol was the one that was different. Further investigation led me to add this to the android section of Module's build.gradle (see also: [PackagingOptions doNotStrip documentation](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions:doNotStrip)
):

```
android {
    .
    .
    packagingOptions {
        doNotStrip "**/*.so"
    }
    .
}
```

After a Gradle sync, clean, and rebuild, the md5sum of the .so in app/build/outputs/apk/debug matches the original md5sum.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19049901)

Comment: Updated to include the answer text, instead of a link to another question.